# Can I "Rotate" around a "Database"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, programming

Does the word "rotate" apply to the programming concept of a "database"?

If so, should I rotate *through*, *inside*, or *around* one?

Is there a better way to express "constantly traversing a changing index"?

Comment: You might have better luck with this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JohnFeltz This isn't necessarily a technical question. I could also ask [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) or [physics.stackexchange.com](http://physics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: There may be many ways to navigate around within a computer database.  How you describe this depends on both the specific database design and the way you wish to navigate.  There is no general implication to the verb "rotate" applicable across all scenarios, so no way, outside of some specific context, to tell you how to use the verb.

Comment: I presume that you are constantly checking the database for new records which match some set of criteria or you are checking that the index does not need reorganising. If either of these is the case you are _monitoring_ the database.

Answer (score 0):

A database index is highly analogous to the index at the back of a book. I think the verb "scan" would be much more appropriate than "rotate".

Comment: Not every database even has an explicit index, and some have several.